# RegQueryInfoKey() function returns different value

Tags: winapi, mfc, registry

In **RegQueryInfoKey** function, it puts wrong results into **dwcValues**, **dwcMaxValueName** and **dwcMaxValueData** value.
**dwcValues** is how many ports are connected, but it has one more count even nothing connected.

For example, when nothing's connected, it shows **dwcValues**=1,**dwcMaxValueName**=17,**dwcMaxValueData**=10.

If one port is connected, it shows **dwcValues**=2,**dwcMaxValueName**=17,**dwcMaxValueData**=10.

I want to know why it happens like this and solve this problem.

```
CString CSerialPort::GetPortName()
{
    DWORD dwcSubKeys,dwcValues,dwcMaxSubKeyName,dwcMaxValueName,dwcMaxValueData;
    dwcSubKeys=dwcValues=dwcMaxSubKeyName=dwcMaxValueName=dwcMaxValueData=0;
    DWORD dwSubKeyIndex = 0;
    DWORD dwValueIndex = 0;
    HKEY hKey = 0;
    LONG lStatus = ERROR_SUCCESS;

    TCHAR szValueName[255] = {0};
    TCHAR szValueData[255] = {0};

    lStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,_T("HARDWARE\\DEVICEMAP\\SERIALCOMM"),0,KEY_READ,&hKey);

    if (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        RegQueryInfoKey(hKey, NULL, NULL, 0,
            &dwcSubKeys, &dwcMaxSubKeyName, NULL,
            &dwcValues, &dwcMaxValueName, &dwcMaxValueData,
             NULL, NULL);

        if (dwcValues != 0) {
            do {
                DWORD dwcValueName = sizeof(szValueName);
                DWORD dwcValueData = sizeof(szValueData);
                lStatus = RegEnumValue(hKey, dwValueIndex,
                        szValueName, &dwcValueName,
                        NULL, NULL,
                        (BYTE*)szValueData,
                        &dwcValueData);
                dwValueIndex++;
            } while (lStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS);
        }
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
    }
    return szValueData;
}
```

Comment: Did you forgot to count the default (unnamed) value?

Comment: @RaymondChen Which one you mean? I set dwcValues to the default value (0) at the beginning.

Comment: Every registry key has an unnamed value, which is called "(Default)" in RegEdit. This is in addition to the named values like "\Device\Serial0".

Comment: @RaymondChen In my computer, dwcValues is 0 when nothing's connected. But in other computer, it's 1 even when nothing's connected.

Comment: It's possible that someone deleted the (Default) value on your computer. But it's there by default.

Comment: @RaymondChen then.. Do you know how to make it work? I need to release this program for students. So, it must be working in any computer.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "make it work". It's working correctly. It is reporting the default value. If you don't care about the default value, then skip it. (It's the one whose name is blank.)

Comment: @RaymondChen No, it's not working correctly.. Even though there's nothing connected, it returns "COM1" string from register. That's why. It should have returned ""(blank) or (default) as you said. But it returns "COM1".

Comment: @RaymondChen I'll add some more informations. The values must be returned as dwcValues=0,dwcMaxValueName=0,dwcMaxValueData=0 and it works well in my computer like that. But in the other computer, becaue the dwcValues is not zero(0), it goes to if(dwcValues!=0) condition below. Because of this reason, the whole function returns "COM1" instead of ""(blank). But it should have returned ""(blank), which means it didn't go through if(dwcValues!=0) condition.

Comment: Described issue has nothing to do with Reg* api itself it seems, so title is a bit misleading. On unrelated note, sizeof's are wrong, not to mention there's no need to use TCHARs in a first place.

Comment: As I noted, if you don't want to count the default value, you need to ignore the item with no name. But the fact that the whole function returns "COM1" means that there was in fact a serial device, so it's not clear why you are saying that it should return blank.